# What is the definition of "here" in "here you go?"

Tags: meaning

Here has two definitions:

> In, at, or to this place or position:
>   'they have lived here most of their lives'
>   Used when indicating a time, point, or situation that has arrived or is happening:
>   'here we encounter the main problem'

So in the idiom "here you go" which definition is used? Is the present tense in this sentence used to signify future action like "my train leaves at seven" or something else?

Comment: It's a set phrase.  Which means that it can't be analyzed word for word.  When the clerk at the store hands me my purchase and says "Here ya go," it just means "I just gave you what you wanted."  He's not telling me to proceed to some place.

Comment: Similarly, if the clerk says "Here you are", he is not indicating your location but saying. "Here is the thing you asked for"

Comment: "Here you go" in the context of someone handing you a package is an example of the 1st definition in that the place where the package exchanges hands is the "here".  A similarly sounding expression, "there you go", means "that's an example of....".

Comment: I understand that it's a set phrase, but I am just curious about the literal meaning. For example, in "Fred kicked the bucket" it means that Fred died, but we also understand the literal meaning of a bucket being kicked.

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary:  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/here-you-go

Comment: It is an idiom and elliptic. The question is not "what is the meaning of here?" , but how can "Here you go" become a formula used when handing someone something he wanted (AmE). I have no idea and found nothing. Perhaps: Here you go with what you wanted or something similar. The British formula is "Here you are".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really mean anything at all. It's just a placeholder where a subject is required to make it grammatical. The word "it" in the sentence, "It is raining." has a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: it's a performative and involves giving or handing something to someone or finding something for someone. It indicates something is being pointed to physically or mentally.

It accompanies the gesture of giving something to someone:
Here [hand moves toward the other person] you go [is the thing].
You might kick a ball to child and say: Here you go.

In referring to non-physical things, the idea of the physical gesture is neverless under the surface.

To sum up, it accompanies the performance of a physical or mental gesture.